# Can't amend a suggested edit from within a review queue

Tags: bug, review, suggested-edits

Seven simple steps to screen-smashing rage:

1. Log in to a site where `500 <= rep < 2000`.
2. Wait for a First Post or Late Answer review task to appear.
3. Decide the post in question needs an edit.
4. Click <kbd>edit</kbd>, and prepare and submit the edit from within the review queue.
5. Realise you missed something and would like to amend the edit (suggested edits can be changed before approval).
6. Click <kbd>edit</kbd> again and get booted to `/posts/whatever/edit`.
7. Realise you have to wait however long (5 minutes?) for the review lock to expire and the task to reappear for you.

IE 11 on Win RT 8.1.

Comment: I'm getting the impression that someone who finishes a review while you're working to edit during the review can take credit for the review and prevent you from getting any credit toward badges yourself...Is that right? That seems like the core problem if so...I mean, this is ultimately about badges, right? Not the ability to clear the review queue and perform edits at all?

Comment: @NickStauner (Oops, just realised that the review-lock means nobody else can get it either.) I *would* like shiny badges... but the root bug is the edit button stops "working" the second time you click it.